# Javascript Object for Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, events, jsobject

Complete newbie here on the Javascript topic. I am trying to code out a Tic Tac Toe game, while using JS' Objects to save code space. I figured I might create a JS Object which will all 9 fields defined in the HTML code with ids 'one' to 'nine' as values, and then also have a custom method which can be used to swap value's textContent as follows:

```
var fields = {
    one: document.querySelector('#one'),
    two: document.querySelector('#two'),
    three: document.querySelector('#three'),
    four: document.querySelector('#four'),
    five: document.querySelector('#five'),
    six: document.querySelector('#six'),
    seven: document.querySelector('#seven'),
    eight: document.querySelector('#eight'),
    nine: document.querySelector('#nine'),
    swap: function(element) {
        if (this.element.textContent === "") {
            this.element.textContent = "X";
        } else if (this.element.textContent === "X") {
            this.element.textContent = "O";
        } else {
            this.element.textContent = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I figured I would just add a bunch of addEventListeners like so:

```
fields['one'].addEventListener('click', fields.swap(fields['one']));
```

The thing is, I am probably totally treating this concept as it would operate in Python, and I am probably messing up the syntax here. Can anyone give me some ideas on where I am making an error?

The code copied above does not work at the moment.

HTML that it works with is as follows (I have omitted formatting here to save on space):

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <table id="gameboard">
      <tr class="row">
      <td id="one" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="two" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="three" class="gameField">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td id="four" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="five" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="six" class="gameField">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td id="seven" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="eight" class="gameField">X</td>
      <td id="nine" class="gameField">X</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Which is the error?

Comment: Welcome to JS! Can you provide the blurb of HTML this works with? The more code you give us the easier it is for us to drop into an editor and debug.

Comment: When calling fields['one'].swap(fields['one']) I get "VM297:1 Uncaught TypeError: fields.one.swap is not a function at <anonymous>:1:15", and when I call it as fields.swap(fields['one']), I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at Object.swap (<anonymous>:12:24) at <anonymous>:1:8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate you **swap** function out of your object and just get rid of the object all together. Add a **class** to all of the HTMLElements you wish to add an EventListener to and then query them all using the following:

```
<div id="one" class="your-class"></div>
<div id="two" class="your-class"></div>

function swap(element) {
   if (element.textContent === ""){
      element.textContent = "X";
    }else if (element.textContent === "X") {
      element.textContent = "O";
    }else {
      element.textContent = "";
    }
}

document.querySelectorAll('.your-class').forEach(function (element) {
   element.addEventListener('click', swap(element));
});
```

Comment: The code above only executes for all the elements the swap() function once on refresh of the page.

Comment: You probably need to remove all the ‘this’s from you swap function. I missed that before. Also, this was just pseudo code, wasn’t run anywhere for correctness. It was to express the concept.

Answer (score 1):

### Tic-Tac-Vue!

Just add styles, sorry got carried away, maybe it's of some interest.

```js
//
const board = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      plays: 0,
      player: true,
      winner: '',
      board: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetGame() {
      this.plays = 0
      this.winner = ''
      this.board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board))
    },
    isBool(value) {
      return typeof(value) === typeof(true)
    },
    play(x, y) {
      if (!this.isBool(this.board[x][y]) && this.winner === '') {
        this.board[x][y] = this.player
        this.plays++
          this.checkWin(this.player)
        this.player = !this.player
      }
    },
    slot(x, y) {
      return {
        'fa-circle-o': this.isBool(this.board[x][y]) && this.board[x][y] === true,
        'fa-times': this.isBool(this.board[x][y]) && this.board[x][y] === false
      }
    },
    endGame(player) {
      this.winner = player
    },
    checkWin(player) {
      // check horizontal win
      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (this.board[i][0] === player &&
          this.board[i][1] === player &&
          this.board[i][2] === player) {
          this.endGame(player);
        }
      }
      // check vertical win
      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (this.board[0][i] === player &&
          this.board[1][i] === player &&
          this.board[2][i] === player) {
          this.endGame(player);
        }
      }
      // check diagonal win
      if ((this.board[0][0] === player &&
          this.board[1][1] === player &&
          this.board[2][2] === player) ||
        this.board[0][2] === player &&
        this.board[1][1] === player &&
        this.board[2][0] === player) {
        this.endGame(player);
      }
      if (this.plays === 9) {
        this.endGame(-1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<style>
  table tr td {
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<div id="app">

  <h3>Tic-Tac-Vue</h3>

  <p>It's player <i :class="['fa', {'fa-circle-o': player, 'fa-times': !player}]"></i>'s go!</p>

  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td @click="play(0,0)"><i :class="['fa', slot(0,0)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(0,1)"><i :class="['fa', slot(0,1)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(0,2)"><i :class="['fa', slot(0,2)]"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td @click="play(1,0)"><i :class="['fa', slot(1,0)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(1,1)"><i :class="['fa', slot(1,1)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(1,2)"><i :class="['fa', slot(1,2)]"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td @click="play(2,0)"><i :class="['fa', slot(2,0)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(2,1)"><i :class="['fa', slot(2,1)]"></i></td>
      <td @click="play(2,2)"><i :class="['fa', slot(2,2)]"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p v-if="winner === true || winner === false">Player <i :class="['fa', {'fa-circle-o': !player, 'fa-times': player}]"></i> is the winner!!</p>
  <p v-if="winner === -1">Game Over, Draw!!</p>
  <button @click="resetGame()">Reset Game</button>
</div>
```

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ktbphaf/

Answer (score 0):

So funny thing, I have solved this problem with bits of Jeremy Dejno's code, but had to adjust it. Taking into account the HTML code I posted in the first post, here's what worked for me:

```
function swap(){
    if (this.textContent === ""){
      this.textContent = "X";
    }else if (this.textContent === "X") {
      this.textContent = "O";
    }else {
      this.textContent = "";
    }
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.gameField').forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click',swap);
  })
```

Since this is a completely new thing for me (I am coming from a Python background), can someone tell me if I understand this correctly: After calling .addEventListener on every item with .gameField class, a swap function is called on every click event on any of them, and the swap function can be called without any arguments because THIS keyword makes it try to modify .textContent property of whatever object it is called on?