# How do I determine a winner in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

I've been trying to figure out how can I use WinCombos to determine a winner but failed.

How can I compare my array (winCombos) with the cells in a 3x3 tic tac toe board to determine a winner?

```
var player1 = "X";
var player2 = "O";
let currentClass = player1
const winCombos = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [6, 4, 2]
] 


let cells = document.querySelectorAll(".row>div");
console.log(cells);

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
   cells[i].addEventListener('click', cellClicked, {once: true})
   var j =  cells[i] 
}


function cellClicked(){
  if(currentClass == player1){
    event.target.textContent = currentClass;
    currentClass = player2;
    if(checkWin(currentClass)){
      console.log("winner");
    }        
  }else{
    currentClass == player2;
    event.target.textContent = currentClass;
    currentClass = player1;
  }
}
```

Comment: A lot of very similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16571035/1316346

Comment: obligatory plug, [du it with vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049591/javascript-object-for-tic-tac-toe-game/52050802#52050802) dont forget to upvote ;p

Comment: @kevinDitraglia Thank you for your help!

Comment: @lawrenceCherone Thank you for your help! I'll check out your answer!

Comment: @dang Finally got an answer! Thank you for your previous advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) in order to accomplish our goal.

```js
function checkWin(player) {
    return winCombos.some(v => v.every(k => cells[k].textContent == player));
}
```